# How do I set my profile picture in Outlook for Mac 2011?

Tags: mac, microsoft-outlook-2011, office-for-mac

How do I set my profile picture so that people can see my smiling face when they read e-mail messages from me?

I've tried Outlook > Preferences > Accounts, but there are no options for a photo in there.

I also tried to find myself in my contacts list, but I'm not in there either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out I was on the right track looking in the Contacts list.
There is an "organize" tab in the contact-list's ribbon/tool-bar.
In the Organize tab is a "Me" button that gave me access to what I needed.

I found the answer in [this article](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2012/07/13/removing-an-unwanted-photo-from-outlook-2011s-me-contact/)
after much googling.